# $http angularjs shows error on callback

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I tested my php alone and it gave me this result

```
{"tabId":1,"tabName":"Main","uId":"1"}{"tabId":2,"tabName":"Photography","uId":"1"}
```

but my angularjs can't receive the callback, it return an error somewhere in angularjs

```
userId = '1';

$http({
    url: "php/loadTab.php",
    method: "GET",
    params: {'userId':userId}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
```

the wierd thing I reuse the exact ajax code and it worked previously. Any thought on this?

the error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.parse (native)

the more strange thing : I purposely add another echo on my php and it able to console the value. what?!

Comment: This code by itself seems correct so it's probably an issue with your web service.

Comment: what is the error that it returns?

Comment: @adrichman SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: your response data needs to be contained in one object

Answer (score 1):

The data from the server isn't valid JSON.

`$httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse` will try to parse the JSON if the data looks like JSON.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

To fix this you could make the parent an array of objects like this

```
[{"tabId":1,"tabName":"Main","uId":"1"},{"tabId":2,"tabName":"Photography","uId":"1"}]
```

Comment: good finding! I don't want it to be JSON, I want it to be normal js objects, how?

Comment: JSON = JS objects, the problem here is that multiple JS objects should be inside array brackets `[]`. Rather than trying to reconfigure angular's `$http` parser, I would suggest using PHP's `json_encode`